# How to create multiple objects at once and push inside an array

Tags: javascript

I wanted objects like this:

```
  [{ age: 3, area: 5 }, 
   { age: 4, area: 15 }, 
   { age: 19, area: 3 }, 
   { age: 16, area: 11 }, 
   { age: 20, area: 4 }, 
   { age: 6, area: 9 }]
```

The approach was to create new objects each time and push it inside an array.

```
  function Numstuff(age,area) {
      this.age = age,
      this.area = area
  }

  var numObjArray = []

var createObj = new Numstuff (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), 
Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))



numObjArray.push(createObj)
```

But This pushes only one. How to create multiple objects and push inside an array?

Comment: If you're sure you're never going to use the `NumStuff` constructor without wanting the new object added to the array, you can put `numObjArray.push(this)` at the end of the constructor.

Comment: Or, if all values will be generated the same way, just use a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array directly with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and fill it with your objects by passing a function:

```js
function Numstuff(age,area) {
    this.age = age,
    this.area = area
}

// make 10 numstuffs
const num = 10
let arr = Array.from({length: num}, () => new Numstuff (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```js
var array = [];
var obj = {};

for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){
  
  obj = {age: i, area: Math.random()}
  array.push(obj);
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Why are you creating all the extra empty objects?

Comment: @MarkMeyer  are you talking about  `obj `?

Comment: Yes, `let obj = {age: i, area: Math.random()}` in the loop is enough. You don't need the other `obj = {}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a for loop. Using you own code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var createObj = new Numstuff (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20), 
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))
    numObjArray.push(createObj)
}
```